# Find at what initial velocity can the projectile reach $8534m?$ Find velocity and $x$ value when projectile reach $8543m$, without using Graph Method.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, physics, projectile-motion

How can I solve this problem *not graphically*? If it is not possible, what more information do I need?

> At what initial velocity can the projectile reach $8534m?$ Find velocity and $x$ value when the projectile reach $8543m$.

$$x(T) = v\cos(θ)T$$
$$y(T)= h + v\sin(θ)T + \frac12 gT^2$$

Given (with proper units)
$h = 83m\\θ = 89°\\g = -9.8m/sec^2$

Comment: you can solve this problem using algebra and basic calculus. no more information is needed (other than possibly a clarification of what "reach 8534m" means, as it can be interpreted in several different ways).

Comment: You can solve it using the equations of motion in two dimensions of projectile motion.

Comment: Find T from the second (quadratic) equation. Them plug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x$($t$)$=vcos(\theta)t$ $\rightarrow$ ①    and $y(t)=h+vsin(\theta)t+\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ $\rightarrow$②

*you want to know the initial velocity of a projectile when it reach a height$=8534$ which will be in this case the max height the projectile have reached this means that the velocity in vertical direction will be equal to zero , $v_y$$=0$*

$\frac{dy}{dt}$$=0$,$\frac{dy}{dt}=vsin(\theta)+gt$$=0$,$vsin(\theta)=-gt$ $\rightarrow$③

*the term $(vsin(\theta))$ will be equal to ($-gt$) at the instant of reacting that height* then we can use this conclusion and substitute in  ②

$8534=83-gt^2+\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ we can solve this quadratic eqation and $t=41.5 sec$

*use that $t=41.5$ and substitute in ③* *you will get that $v=406.79$ $m/sec$*

*for the $x$ value substitute by $t=41.5$ and $v=406.79$ in ①
and you will get that $x=294.607$* $meter$